# Set first and last row colors

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am looking to set the first row green and last row red and all inbetween rows orange in a sorted group.
what comparison can i use to check if its the top value or first row?

thank you

Answer (score 12):

For the first row

```
=IIF(RowNumber("DataSet1") = 1, firstRowColor, OtherRowColor)
```

For the last row

```
=IIF(RowNumber("DataSet1") = CountRows("DataSet1"), lastRowColor, OtherRowColor)
```

To combine the two,

```
=IIF(RowNumber("DataSet1") = 1, firstRowColor, 
 IIF(RowNumber("DataSet1") = CountRows("DataSet1"), lastRowColor, OtherRowColor))
```

Comment: Thanks, nearly works but the RowNumber("DataSet1") = 1 for the first row doesn't work as it returns a higher value, probably because its and aggregated value. any idea how i could compare that. thank you.

Comment: You might be able to do something with the `First` and `Last` functions.

Comment: @user2329438 did you try changing the scope to a group context?

"MyGroup1" or something similar.